# See Other Players Message Ratings

Tags: bloodborne

Checking other players' messages only show you have many people have rated a message (appraisals) but not the number of fine/foul votes.

In Dark Souls, there was the [Seek Guidance miracle](http://darksouls.wiki.fextralife.com/Seek+Guidance) that allowed you to see other players' true ratings.  Does something like that exist in Bloodborne?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have played through the game four times, acquired every magic item that could potentially reveal the votes, and still have not found a way to view the number of fine and foul votes.

Given that it has been more than a year since the game was released, and all the reliable internet sources still don't have any answers to this question, I believe it's safe to say that the ability for the player to view the number of fine vs. foul votes on another player's message does not exist in the game.